# RShiny: How to center sliders

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyjs

I am new to RShiny and I am trying to replicate this template: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/retirement-simulation.html
I do have the code for this template but this is a learning exercise.

Here is what I have so far:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Title goes here...
  titlePanel("Retirement: simulating wealth with random returns, inflation and withdrawals"),
  p("Description here..."),
  hr(),

  # Sidebar layout...
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar panel...
    sidebarPanel(
      # Input: Slider for the number of observations to generate ----
      sliderInput("n",
                  "Param 1",
                  value = 500,
                  min = 1,
                  max = 1000),
      sliderInput("n",
                  "Param 2",
                  value = 500,
                  min = 1,
                  max = 1000),
      sliderInput("n",
                  "Param 3",
                  value = 500,
                  min = 1,
                  max = 1000),
      sliderInput("n",
                  "Param 4",
                  value = 500,
                  min = 1,
                  max = 1000)
    ),

    # Main panel...
    mainPanel(
      # Outputs of any plots...
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot"))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

It looks good but I need the sliders to be centered just like the template above. Very grateful for pointers in the right direction!

Thanks,

Joesph

Comment: Use the `column` arguments in your sidebar panel...other option is to use `box` to set boxes around your sliders to have more fine tuned control

Comment: Thanks. I've played around with this but I don't understand the column width 1-12 part. How do I get 16 sliders to align 4 by 4 just like the example above?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a combination of wellPanel, fluidRow and column.

The first fluidRow is to hold the 2 wellPanels side by side with a 50% split. Within each of the wellPanels, we use fluidRows to define a row and then 2 columns with width 6 to define 2 columns of 50% width.

```
ui <- navbarPage("Test",

     tabPanel("Data",

              fluidRow(column(
                6,
                wellPanel(
                  fluidRow(column(
                    6, sliderInput("input1", "input1", 0, 100, 5)
                  ),
                  column(
                    6, sliderInput("input2", "input2", 0, 100, 5)
                  )),

                  fluidRow(column(
                    6, sliderInput("input1", "input3", 0, 100, 5)
                  ),
                  column(
                    6, sliderInput("input3", "input4", 0, 100, 5)
                  )),

                  fluidRow(column(
                    6, sliderInput("input1", "input5", 0, 100, 5)
                  ),
                  column(
                    6, sliderInput("input2", "input6", 0, 100, 5)
                  ))
                )
              ))))
```

The final output would look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin: auto` CSS rule:

```
div(style = "margin: auto; width: 80%", # this number can be any percentage you need
    sliderInput(
                ...
                width = "100%" # this number has to be "100%", nothing less
               )
   )
```